# How to configure an extra/different migrations folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, directory, migration

A colleague and I are working in different projects that share some models. So, we are sharing the models through a git submodule.

Additionally, we'd like to be able to also share migrations:

In this way, my colleague's migrations would be in the folder `db/migrate/other_db` of my project.

How can I configure rails migrations to also run the migrations in this extra folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update for Rails 5/6;

Rails 5 recommends setting additional migration paths in your `config/database.yml` file. It's very easy, see this example;

```
development:
  migrations_paths:
  - "db/migrate/other_db"
  - "db/migrate/something_else"
```

`ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_path=` will be deprecated in Rails 6.

Comment: `migration_paths` appears to have been moved to ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations instead of being deprecated: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/31b1403919eec0973921ab42251bfbbf3d4422b6/activerecord/lib/active_record/database_configurations/hash_config.rb#L45

Comment: Rails 7 documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DatabaseConfigurations/HashConfig.html#method-i-migrations_paths

Answer (score 32):

In your config file (config/application.rb for all environments or config/environments/$(environment).rb only for particular environment) add this line:

```
config.paths['db/migrate'] += 'db/migrate/other_db'
```

And if you want to change default 'db/migrate' path (config.paths['db/migrate'] is an array with one string 'db/migrate' by default), do this:

```
config.paths['db/migrate'] = ['db/my_migrate']
```

Here are default config.paths, which we also can change:

```
"app" => ["app"],
"app/assets" => ["app/assets"],
"app/controllers" => ["app/controllers"],
"app/helpers" => ["app/helpers"],
"app/models" => ["app/models"],
"app/mailers" => ["app/mailers"],
"app/views" => ["app/views"],
"lib" => ["lib"],
"lib/assets" => ["lib/assets"],
"lib/tasks" => ["lib/tasks"],
"config" => ["config"],
"config/environments" => ["config/environments"],
"config/initializers" => ["config/initializers"],
"config/locales" => ["config/locales"],
"config/routes" => ["config/routes.rb"],
"db" => ["db"],
"db/migrate" => ["db/migrate"],
"db/seeds" => ["db/seeds.rb"],
"vendor" => ["vendor"],
"vendor/assets" => ["vendor/assets"],
"vendor/plugins" => ["vendor/plugins"],
"config/database" => ["config/database.yml"],
"config/environment" => ["config/environment.rb"],
"lib/templates" => ["lib/templates"],
"log" => ["log/development.log"],
"public" => ["public"],
"public/javascripts" => ["public/javascripts"],
"public/stylesheets" => ["public/stylesheets"],
"tmp" => ["tmp"],
```

Comment: In Rails 4: `config.paths['db/migrate'] << 'db/migrate/other_db'`

Comment: The correct answer is `config.paths['db/migrate'] << 'db/migrate/other_db'` for Rails 3 or 4.

Comment: `config.paths['db/migrate'] += ['db/migrate/other_db'] ` would also work.

Comment: @apocalyptiq is there any way to change images and stylesheets directory alone in assets???

Like 'app/assets/images' => 'apples/assets/images' ?

Comment: Note that until at least Rails 4.2, it was not (easily?) possible to override migrations_path because it _always_ attempts to set the default: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L874

Comment: With Rails 6, it picks up the migrations from subdirectory automatically

Answer (score 4):

based on the answer by Swanand, we can write a migration to load the migrations in an external dir:

```
class MigrateMetadata < ActiveRecord::Migration
  MIGRATIONS_PATH='db/migrate/metadata'
  def self.up
   Dir["#{MIGRATIONS_PATH}/[0-9]*_*.rb"].
   sort.map{|filename|require filename}.flatten.
   each{|class_name| const_get(class_name).up}
  end

  def self.down
    Dir["#{MIGRATIONS_PATH}/[0-9]*_*.rb"].sort.reverse.
    map{|filename|require filename}.flatten.
    each{|class_name| const_get(class_name).down}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of a very clean way to do it, but the code that runs migrations looks something like:

```
@migrations ||= begin                                                                                                                                            
        files = Dir["#{@migrations_path}/[0-9]*_*.rb"]                                                                                                                 

        migrations = files.inject([]) do |klasses, file|                                                                                                               
          version, name = file.scan(/([0-9]+)_([_a-z0-9]*).rb/).first
```

Where,

```
@migrations_path = 'db/migrate'
```

So if you change this to read from config file instead, it may work out in your favour. But as I said, this is definitely not a very clean way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, if you are building a gem to work with Rails, you can place a block like the following in your rail tie to add the gem's own migrations.

```
  root = ... # the path to your gem
  initializer :append_migrations do |app|
    unless app.root.to_s.match root
      app.config.paths["db/migrate"] << File.join(root, 'db/migrate')
    end
  end
```

There is no need to copy migrations from your gem with generators if you use this technique.

You can make a method to yield the root directory of your gem with some thing like this...

```
module MyGemName
  def root
    File.expand_path '../..', __FILE__
  end

  module_method :root
end
```

... in the file lib/my_gem_name.rb in your gem.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this initializer to your lib/engine.rb:

```
initializer 'your_engine_name.migrations' do |app|
  config.paths['db/migrate'].expanded.each do |expanded_path|
    app.config.paths['db/migrate'] << expanded_path
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths << expanded_path

    if Rake.application.top_level_tasks.empty?
      ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?
    end
  end

end
```