# Rails Engine migrations to a different folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

[Reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888570/how-to-configure-an-extra-different-migrations-folder)

Our group works with a common application but we also individually work on Engines. Is there a configuration is Rails 3 that allows us to put Engine-related migrations files on a different folder? 
The goal is to track our migrations in Git, but also separate migrations related to the common app from the ones for Engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually name migrations whatever you want. [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration). I would suggest the following convention.

```
[DATE]_[ENGINE_NAME|CORE]_[DESCRIPTION].rb
```

There you go!