# Change default directory of migration files for rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I would like to use two independent migration logic in a project that requires two separated directories for migration files. Is there any way to change the default directory of rake db:migrate?

For instance:

```
DIR="db/migrations_other" rake db:migrate
```

Or how can you use other directory for migration files instead of db/migrate?

Comment: Here is a similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888570/how-to-configure-an-extra-different-migrations-folder

Comment: Thanks. I don't use Rails, so this config change didn't help me, but it was good to start.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way. I created a rake task for the other migration, here is the task:

```
namespace :db_2 do
  task :migrate => :environment do
    ActiveRecord::Migration.verbose = ENV["VERBOSE"] ? ENV["VERBOSE"] == "true" : true
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("db/migrate_other/", ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil)
  end
end
```

So now I just run

```
rake db_2:migrate
```

and it uses the other directory.